# Failed to define class org.richfaces.context.PartialViewContextImpl in Module

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2, servletexception

After deploying of my war file in wildfly 9 it showing this error in the console logs please help me.

Failed to define class org.richfaces.context.PartialViewContextImpl in Module "deplodule "deployment.hello.war:main" from Service Module Loader)

```
     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:269)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:560)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxStateManager.writeState(AjaxStateManager.java:56)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl$WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(ViewHandlerImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:210)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:198)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:195)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:692)
```

2.Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/context/PartialViewContextWrapper

```
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:353)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:432)
    ... 77 more
```

3.Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper from [Module "deployment.hellobean.war:main" from Service Modul$

```
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
```

4.ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-6) UT005023: Exception handling request to /hellobean/login.jsp: javax.servlet.ServletException

```
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:848)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:777)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:86)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:366)
```

Comment: Here we go the scene creator it's self decrypt the enigma...

Comment: The thing is that we need to delete richfaces-impl-jsf2.jar and keep the jsf-impl-1.2.jar file that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I solved it removing the following jar on /lib

richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.3.Final.jar (delete)

And restart the application.

I think it has conflicts with this jar:

richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar